# How to use "pan screen" on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have found a function recently in Android Studio named "pan screen". It is located at the right side of design window. But I didn't find any description for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you zoom in your design much enough so it no longer fits on in your design area in Android Studio, you can hit pan icon and drag your design around.

Answer (score 0):

The image you have shown in is `Zoom and Pan Controls` which allows you to zoom in and out of the design , Now the `Pan button` will help you to pan around to find the areas
that are unable or not visible to see when zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Pan is swing in a horizontal or vertical plane, typically to give a panoramic effect or follow a subject.
Pan in Android studio, you can hold space bar and drag the screen to view those area currently is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

When a user zooms in the layout so much that you are unable to see all items in the layout, you can click on the pan option and then afterwards move the layout without accidently moving the items in the layout.